# Install all packages from given yum repo

Tags: yum

How can I install all packages from given yum repo? Yum list contains a header and you cannot tell it to print only the first line.

Comment: You can install all update packages.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for providing a good answer. However, I find that this way is simpler and doesn't require `yum-utils`:

```
sudo yum --disablerepo=\* --enablerepo=my-cool-repo install \*
```

That being said, `yum-utils` is useful for other things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of yum, use repoquery from package yum-utils.

```
repoquery --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=my-cool-repo -a | xargs sudo yum -y install
```